# How to call the destructor of a derived class in a vector in another class

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

I have a class that has a `std::vector` of pointers to a base class that has different derived classes.  How do I call their destructors from within the `vector` class?

holder.h

```
class holder
{
public:
    void add_stuff();
    void do_stuff();        
private:
    std::vector<base*> vect;
};
```

holder.cpp

```
void holder::add_stuff(base* to_add) {
    vect.push_back(to_add);
}

void holder::do_stuff() {
    vect[0]->say_words();
    delete vect[0]; //<--<--<-- I want to delete the object now
}
```

Feel free to stop now if you know what I'm doing wrong.  I've included the basics of what the rest of the code looks like, in case I'm just way off.

base.h

```
class base
{
public:
    base();
    virtual ~base();
    virtual void say_words() = 0;
};
```

derived.h

```
class derived : public base
{
public:
    derived();
    ~derived();
    void say_words();
};
```

derived.cpp

```
derived::derived() {}
derived::~derived() {}

void derived::say_words() {
    cout << "Words!" << endl;
}
```

main.cpp

```
holder hold;
holder* H = &hold;
int main(){
    base* d = new derived();
    H->add_stuff(d);
    H->do_stuff();
}
```

Comment: Don't.  Use a `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shard_ptr` instead of a raw pointer and then use `erase` on the vector to remove.  That will handle the memory management for you(that's a good thing).

Comment: Don't post pseudo-code.  Post [MCVE].

Comment: What is the real constraint behind destroying objects at this exact point in code?

Comment: I just want to make sure the object is deleted after it's used.  If there's a better way to do it, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I call their destructors from within the `vector` class?

You already are, by virtue of the fact that the `~base` destructor is marked as `virtual`.  Calling `delete` on a pointer to the base class will automatically call all of the derived destructors for you.  That is *WHY* the base class destructor needs to be declared as `virtual` in the first place.

What you are missing, though, is removing the object pointer from your `std::vector` after you `delete` the object, eg:

```
void holder::do_stuff() {
    vect[0]->say_words();
    delete vect[0]; // <-- calls all destructors of this object!
    vect.erase(vect.begin()); // <-- add this line!
}
```

You don't want to leave invalid pointers in your container.